# Correct way of using insert statement with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to insert the data in database using the following code.
Is it the correct way of doing it?
I am not able to add the data using the following statements in the database.

```
try {

 # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

  /*** INSERT data ***/ 

    $task = $_POST['task'];
    $target_date = $_POST['target_date'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO animals(task, target_date) VALUES (:task, :target_date)";
    $q=$DBH->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':task'=>$task,':target_date'=>$target_date));


    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $DBH = null;

 }
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is OK. Please elaborate on "I am not able to add the data..."

Comment: btw and probably matter of opinion: It would work just as fine without the (superfluous) variables `$task` and `$target_date` - `$q->execute(array(':task'=>$_POST['task'],':target_date'=>$_POST['target_date']));`

Comment: @VolkerK . Thanks I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a catch/echo-message block you should turn on ERRMODE_EXCEPTION on your pdo instance in order to see what's going wrong.

```
try{
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  ...


}
catch(...)
```

see http://docs.php.net/pdo.error-handling